# Voiceover having problem to pronounce non-english options from select dropdown

Tags: html, macos, accessibility, html-select, voiceover

I am trying to implement Choose language drop-down in my web application, But it seems that content of option are not being pronounced by voice-over.

It echo's English language content properly, but as soon as non English option is selected from drop-down it is not echoing it.

Below is the html code

```
<label for="lang">Choose Language:</label>
  <select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option>English</option>
    <option>日本人</option>
    <option>русский</option>
    <option>中文</option>
  </select>
```

Please suggest,

Thanks

Comment: `<option lang="zh">` assuming that second one is chinese, give that a go and if it works I will turn into an answer as I can't find if that is valid on an `<option>` - see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp for all the language codes (yeah w3schools.....what can you do?), would be useful to let people know what the languages are in your example too if possible so that we can fiddle with things.

Comment: 2nd option is japanese, 3rd is russian and 4th is chinese

Comment: moreover I have already given a try for it but it seems to be not working in mac voiceover

Comment: here is the link to stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2zakit?file=index.html

Comment: That is a shame that using the `lang` attribute doesn't work. The biggest problem with a `<select>` is that we can't use visually hidden text, `aria-labels` etc. on the options and creating a custom select is likely to reduce accessibility. Where I would suggest to hide the Japanese and then use hidden text to say "Japanese" in English we don't have that option. The only thing I can think is to put all of the languages in English and put the actual language next to them (so `Japanese - 日本人`) as that may get read correctly? This is what we do but I will be honest this is an area we overlooked.

Comment: Leave this with me as it is something we need to address ourselves now I think about it so we can do some research, might take a while but I will bookmark this question and throw ideas down as we test them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, add the lang attribute.

```
  <select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option lang="en">English</option>
    <option lang="ja">日本人</option>
    <option lang="ru">русский</option>
    <option lang="zh">中文</option>
  </select>
```

Using the lang attribute gives a chance to trigger automatic language switch, i.e. make the screen reader automatically select another speech synthesizer appropriate for the language indicated.

Then, don't be afraid. If **your VoiceOver** is unable to speak something written in another language, that's simply because you haven't installed any speech synthesizer for that language.

In the rewritten example above, you can be pretty confident that russians will hear русский correctly, if this text is correctly marked as being russian with the lang attribute, and if they have a russian speech synthesizer installed on their device.
WE assume, of course, that it is naturally the case for a native russian person.

IF you are unsure, you can of course try yourself by installing an appropriate speech synthesizer on your device.

Addition following comments: it seems that VO doesn't take the lang attribute into account in an `<option>` element.

I suggest writing to accessibility@apple.com. That's a VO issue. VO should support the lang attribute in `<option>` elements.
Nothing in the HTML5 spec forbids it, at least. The lang attribute is allowed in every elements that can include text.

However, The `<option>` element doesn't allow other elements inside it in the spec. Thus all solutions based on  a .sr_only span + another aria-hidden span  are invalid.
So the lang attribute is the only correct valid way.
It would be really sad to create a custom combobox just because of this issue.

You may be tempted to simplify / work around the problem by doing the following. Don't!

```
  <select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option>English</option>
    <option>Japanese</option>
    <option>Russian</option>
    <option>Chinese<option>
  </select>
```

The reason to not do this is quite simple: the chinese user landing on your english page may not know english at all, and in particular, don't know that "Chinese" is the right option to select.
He/she's simply going to leave your site for ever, since anyway he/she doesn't understand anything. **Always write the name of a language in the language itself**, i.e. "english, français, español, deutsch" rather than "english, french, spanish, german".